# When can I know the updated status from reviewer or editor after i submit a revised manuscript to that publisher?

Tags: publications, journals, email, editors, chemistry

I have submitted a revised manuscript to an international journal of quantum chemistry at 8 August. My articles status still remain under review, I also don't know my article get accepted or rejected, I feel anxiety and cannot sleep well in this 3 weeks since this is my first articles. Should I write a polite inquiry email to the editor from that publisher to ask the status for my revised manuscript status? Thank you for advice.

Comment: Most likely the manuscript is, in fact, still under review. The new version needs to be looked at and won't be approved in most cases without a look. It is a busy time for academics in most places which may account for any delay. If you need to take action soon, with deadlines for your own action, then you can inquire, but otherwise, patience is advised.

Comment: Buffy, thank you for your advice. I also know that is not so good to write an email to urge the editor. I receive the email says the editor will let me know the decision not more than two months. Can I send the inquiry letter to ask the editor if my revised still in the under review status after two months?

Comment: You can, of course, but be a bit slow and cautious. Unless you need to send the paper elsewhere on a deadline or depend on it for a job interview, there seems to be little real reason to press, other than your own peace of mind. For things like job interviews you can, of course list the publication as "submitted and under review."

Comment: If you are given a timeline from the editor like "not more than two months" you should really take this as a minimum, despite how it is written, and certainly not inquire at all about it until after that period. Giving a timeline is sort of an implicit way of saying "don't bother me about it for this long."

Comment: Buffy, I am grateful for your help and advice. However, my supervisor and I cannot find the place to send in our rebuttal letter for the revised manuscript. We just copy and paste the content from the rebuttal letter to that particular column on the website. Hope this won't be a reason for the editor and reviewers to reject the revised manuscript that has already been sending in.

Comment: If there is a problem with your submission you can expect the editor to contact you. They won't leave it lingering. Take a couple breaths, occupy yourself with something you find relaxing, and then get back to work on your other projects and let this one sit out of your control for a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check with your colleagues in quantum chemistry what the standard timeline in publication is. In particular, you want to know how long it takes to receive reviewer reports. If your colleagues have reviewed papers, you can also ask how long they are given to review.

Chances are very good that 3 weeks is not too long - in fact it'd be abnormally fast to receive a decision in 3 weeks. Therefore relax, and wait.

If you're still concerned, I would [email Wiley](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/1097461x/homepage/contact.html) and ask about the status. They probably won't be able to give you a decision, but you can still ask questions such as how many reviewers have agreed to review, when the review due dates are, and so on (no guarantees they will give you the details though).